# Some Rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

So a rebus puzzle is basically where you have to work out the 'hidden' meaning. For example

[image]

would be

> TH under STORM (because the TH is under the STORM) or Thunderstorm

So I've made 6 puzzles for you to enjoy :) Good luck!

[image]

---

[Part II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47314/some-more-rebus-puzzles) and [III](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47641/even-more-rebus-puzzles)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From left to right, first row then second row:

> Fishin(g) for compliments
> Third time lucky
> Four leaf clover (credit @silenus)
> There is no I in TEAM
> An inside job
>  i <3 u

Comment: Third is "Four leaf clover."

Comment: Good work! Did I make them a bit easy?

Comment: @Wen1now No, they are not too easy. I'm quite fluent in English but still word plays are challenging. I enjoyed that I could solve some of them but not the others.