# Some more rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

I have some more Rebus puzzles:

[image]

Seeing how the [first lot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47279/some-rebus-puzzles-part-i) were a bit easy I decided to make these a bit harder. Good luck!

**HINT FOR 3:**

> It has something to do with the fact that they are numbers i.e letters wouldn't work

**Hint for 3 and 4:**

> For 4, it has something to do with the positioning of a certain letter/letters. For 3, there is no summing involved and the underlining just under lines the last number

---

Next lot: [Even more rebus puzzles!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47641/even-more-rebus-puzzles)

Comment: @Silenus I wanted some variation... Is it possible to change the name of a puzzle?

Comment: PSA: No letters are missing from the alphabet in the bottom left one.

Comment: Since the duck one is kind of misleading (sorry) I have update the photo. And @greenturtle3141 I put all the letters in but it's not that relevant.

Comment: Not sure it matters as the answer was found but normally when you put one word/string 'in' another as part of a cryptic clue it is together as a whole, not interlaced with the other word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Community wiki:

The first one is

> Walking on thin ice (*walking* = stick figure, *on* = position, *thin ice* = 'th' in 'ice')

The second one is

> Sitting duck

The third one is

> Last but not least

The fourth one is

> High L and S = highlands (answer by OP)

The fifth one is

> Back out

The sixth one is

> Hole in one

Answer (score 7):

The bottom row:

> Alphabet soup, back out, hole in one.

Comment: Nice work! 2/3; the first one is somewhat harder than that.

Comment: The second in your list could also refer to the Australian countryside.

Answer (score 7):

First one is

> Walking on thin ice (*walking* = stick figure, *on* = position, *thin ice* = 'th' in 'ice')

Answer (score 5):

I think the second one is

> Sitting duck (clearer after update)

Comment: Yep that's it. Sorry about the old one.

Answer (score 5):

Could the third one be

> This doesn't add up.

because

> for proper summing, you need the numbers to be right aligned?

Answer (score 5):

I think the third one is

> Last but not least

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Yes, this was what was intended... although I do see a lot of other creative options out there

Answer (score 4):

Some alternative guesses..

Third one:

> Bottom line

Fourth one:

> Letter bomb

For the fifth one..

> I quite like 'outback' instead of 'back out' here :)

Comment: Third one could also be *above the line*

Answer (score 2):

I think the second one might be

> THE UGLY DUCK(LING)

Comment: Good guess, but not correct

Answer (score 1):

First:

> Walking on Thin Ice

Second:

> Sitting Duck

Third:

> "In Summary" or "Grand Total"... though I love Glorfindel's answer "This doesn't add up"

Fourth:

> Mix Up

Fifth:

> Backout

Sixth:

> Hole in One

Answer (score 0):

My take on the fourth, based on the hint:

> Cornered (Corner "D")

Any confirmation on which ones are right and which are still yet to be solved?

Answer (score 0):

1. > Walking on thin ice (stick figure walking on thin ice)
2. > Sitting duck ( you'll see the word duck sitting)
3. > Last but not least
4. > Alphabet soup
5. > Backout
6. > Hole in one

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Make sure to check if an answer has already been posted or accepted before sharing your own (only if it adds something). If you would like to learn more about this site and how it works (and get your first badge) check out the tour and help center: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help