# Even more rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

Sequel to [Some rebus puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47279/some-rebus-puzzles) (easy/medium) and [Some more rebus puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47314/some-more-rebus-puzzles) (medium/hard). These puzzles are *hopefully* the right difficulty this time.

Good luck!

[image]

And yes, the last one is supposed to look like that.

---

For more of a challenge try [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47759/revenge-rebus-puzzles)

Comment: I don't believe so; the fifth is the middle bottom right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Full answer*

Number 1 is:

> A piece of cake (*ak* is part of cake, and the drawing is a indeed a piece of cake)

Number 2 is:

> Stay back

Number 3 is:

> Half price

Number 4 is:

> Put him on the back foot

Number 5 is:

> Ace in the hole

Number 6 is:

> Think outside the box

Comment: Good work! I guess I made them too easy again. I'll accept when the time limit is up :)

Answer (score 5):

1

> Middle piece (ak is the middle part in c'ak'e)

2

> Stay back (Stay backward)

3

> Prism (Pri some)

4

> Put him on the backfoot

5

> Ace in the hole

6

> Think outside the box (thanks to @IAmInPLS)

Comment: Good effort; however the third one is incorrect (I don't use words that phonetically sound similar as IMO it's ambiguous)

Comment: (Correct answer has already been accepted)