# Revenge [cryptic] rebus puzzles

Tags: story, rebus, cryptic-clues

Enjoyed [these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47641/even-more-rebus-puzzles) did you? Felt they were a bit too easy? The rebuses are feeling bitter about their loss, and they will only concede defeat if you break their puzzle:

[image]

Wait a second... they've sent a note as well! It seems to be a kind of disjointed story.

> When the only place that's natural dies,
>   Once we undo the damage mixed with and in a large vessel we'll produce noise.
>   Remembering that similar and up to a point chilli is well kept with a secret.
>   During any animal's sleep it's embarrassed that it, without sleeping, is uncertain.
>
> From a scarcely populated place any people having fun were envied except by those with a good first turn
>   In a private book, which I discovered, called 'Snide: where to cook' was yesterday.
>   Realising that shied away, we disrupt. The book conceals a envelope!
>   So we never thought to sanctify the book without me or a priest, named 'int'.
>   That the disappearance there was of a weird beheaded kind of thread was key.

Oooh... and there's a final rebus under that note:

[image]

Can you win this time? Or have the rebuses finally beaten you? Good luck!

---

**Note:** the flavor text is just that, for flavor. There is not hidden information inside that. Obviously the rebuses and the note are important though. [Too many rebus puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48035/too-many-rebus-puzzles) is the next one.

**Edit:** sorry but the fourth rebus isn't really a rebus. Kind of. And also six *should* be two words.

Answer (score 2):

## Partial Solution

Each rebus so far holds a saying:

1.

> ?

2.

> Every cloud has a silver lining

3.

> Useless as a third wheel

<sub>(Partial answer for 4)</sub>

4.

> Hinder, find, rows/sword/word (latter two going back), grid (going up), you (going down), seek (going down-left diagonally), search (going up-right diagonally)

5.

> ?

6.

> ?

Comment: Also, 'YOU', in the wordsearch.

Comment: also "seek" and "sword" or "word" (overlapping "rows")

Comment: also SEARCH in the grid.  (bottom right to upper left)

Answer (score 1):

Partial

**The Note**

> When the only place that's natural dies,
>   Once we undo the damage mixed with and in a large vessel we'll produce noise.
>   Remembering that similar and up to a point chilli is well kept with a secret.
>   During any animal's sleep it's embarrassed that it, without sleeping, is uncertain.
>   From a scarcely populated place any people having fun were envied except by those with a good first turn.
>   In a private book, which I discovered, called 'Snide: where to cook' was yesterday.
>   Realising that shied away, we disrupt. The book conceals a envelope!
>   So we never thought to sanctify the book without me or a priest, named 'int'.
>   That the disappearance there was of a weird beheaded kind of thread was key.

Could be

> First letter of each line gives **WORD FIRST/ FIRST WORD.** Which could be either Revenge/Enjoyed/When

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that last rebus is:

> Sum up, 714 being the sum of the numbers on the left.

The rest have me baffled.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit out there (this is my first rebus puzzle),

> but I've darned convinced myself that the sixth one is dinner. 
>  Backwords e is the shwa in the IPA.

It likely ain't the intention of the puzzle-maker, but just one more idea for y'all!