# Too many rebus puzzles!

Tags: rebus

Recently I've made a bunch of rebuses, and this is the newest lot of 6 (note that I've finally used some colour!).

[image]

**IMPORTANT: update**

> As of now, everything except three is solved. Of course, you can still have the pleasure of solving them,, but that's not the point... and no, it is not redhead :)

---

[Hard rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47759/revenge-rebus-puzzles)

Parts [I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47279/some-rebus-puzzles), [II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47314/some-more-rebus-puzzles) and [III](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47641/even-more-rebus-puzzles) which most of you have probably done.

Comment: For those solving number 3: there's a **red e** - _ready_. This may or may not be relevant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a compilation of others' answers with added explanations (if there wasn't already one).

---

#1 by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan)

> **A: anyone**
>  The line is going up-right, or North-East (NE). It's accompanied by the number 1. NE1.

---

#2 by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper)

> **A: high and dry**
>  *dry* is above *low* (i.e. high).

---

#3 by [Neil W](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12226/neil-w)

> **A: red handed**
>  red h-and-ed

---

#4 by [Roger](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4518/roger)

> **A: middle of the road**
>  th*e ro*ad

---

#5 by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper)

> **A: todo list**
>  2 (two) *do*. List.

---

#6 by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11110/glorfindel)

> **A: beat around the bush**
>  *beat* is split in half, surrounding the word *bush*.

Comment: this should probably be made a community wiki answer, as none of it is your own contribution.

Comment: @Rubio How do I do that?

Comment: See here....  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir8km.png

Comment: mmm Very close, I have posted an update :)

Answer (score 8):

PARTIAL

1. (Helped with designing 1, so I can't answer it. I had no involvement with the rest, though)
2. > High and dry
3. > Redhead?
4. > 
5. > To-do list
6. > 

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer:

4.

> middle of the road

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is wrong because I am not "100% sure" (see Wen1now's comment on Rubio's answer), but #1

> can be interpreted as an arrow going *northeast* labelled "1", hence "NE 1" or "anyone".

Comment: Yep, that's it :)

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution for the last one:

> beat around the bush

I'm not sure it's 100% correct;

> if the 'h' in that picture is intentionally misplaced, I'm probably missing something. Or the 'bus' is supposed to be 'heavy' ...

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I suppose I should have made it **be the bush at** but that seems a bit obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Would 3 be

> Red h-and-ed?

.............

Comment: Yep, that's all of them then :)

Answer (score 3):

**Partial**

1.

> One coming right up?

Comment: Good try, but no. You will be 100% sure when you get it.

Comment: IMO that's better than the official correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I thought #1 was simply

> 1up. To one up somebody basically.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Remember to place your answers in spoiler tags.

Answer (score 1):

Ill try the first one:

1.

> One direction